# React SetState Overwriting Entire Object Instead of Merging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-frontend, react-state

My state looks like this in the constructor:

```
this.state = {
      selectedFile: null, //current file selected for upload.
      appStatus: 'waiting for zip...', //status view
      zipUploaded: false,
      zipUnpacked: false,
      capturingScreens: false, 
      finishedCapture: false, 
      htmlFiles: null, 
      generatedList: [], 
      optionValues: { 
        delayValue: 1
      }, 
      sessionId: null,
      estimatedTime: null,
      zippedBackupFile: null,
      secondsElapsed:0,
      timer: {
        screenshotStart:0,
        screenshotEnd:0,
        timingArray:[],
        averageTimePerUnit:25,
        totalEstimate:0
      }
    };
```

I have the following functions in my app.js:

```
this.secondsCounter = setInterval(this.countSeconds, 1000); // set inside the constructor


getStateCopy = () => Object.assign({}, this.state);

countSeconds = () => {
    let stateCopy = this.getStateCopy();
   
    let currentSeconds = stateCopy.secondsElapsed + 1;

    this.setState({secondsElapsed:currentSeconds});
  }
  captureTime = (startOrStop) => {
    let stateCopy = this.getStateCopy();
    let secondsCopy = stateCopy.secondsElapsed;
    let startPoint;

    if(startOrStop === true) {
      this.setState({timer:{screenshotStart:secondsCopy}});
    } else if(startOrStop === false){
      this.setState({timer:{screenshotEnd:secondsCopy}});
      startPoint = stateCopy.timer.screenshotStart;
      stateCopy.timer.timingArray.push((secondsCopy-startPoint));
      this.setState({secondsElapsed:secondsCopy})
      
      stateCopy.timer.averageTimePerUnit = stateCopy.timer.timingArray.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / stateCopy.timer.timingArray.length;
      this.setState({secondsElapsed:secondsCopy})
      this.setState({timer:{averageTimePerUnit:stateCopy.timer.averageTimePerUnit}})
  
    }
```

I'm getting an error that "push" does not exist on stateCopy.timer.timingArray. I did some investigation and found that this.setState({timer:{screenshotStart:secondsCopy}}); is actually overwriting the entire "timer" object in state and removing all of the previous properties instead of merging them.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.. I'm using stateCopy to avoid mutating state, and to get proper values (avoiding asynchronous confusion). Every article I read online about react suggests that writing an object to state will merge with whatever is already there, so why does it keep overwriting "timer" instead of merging??

Comment: @wyfy - That won't do anything different from `Object.assign`. Cmaxster - Beware they're both **shallow** copies.

Comment: What is a shallow copy? Sorry I’m kind of a beginner..

Comment: Say you have `const obj = {a: 1, b: { c: 1}};`, an object with a property with a number value (`a: 1`) and a property whose value is a reference to an object (`b: {c: 1}`). `Object.assign` (and spread notation) only copy the top level, so `const obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj);` will make `obj.b` and `obj2.b` point to the **same object**.

Answer (score 2):

> I did some investigation and found that this.setState({timer:{screenshotStart:secondsCopy}}); is actually overwriting the entire "timer" object in state and removing all of the previous properties instead of merging them.

Correct. `setState` only handles merging at the *top level*. Anything below that you have to handle yourself. For instance:

```
this.setState(({timer}) => {timer: {...timer, screenshotStart: secondsCopy}});
```

Note the use of the callback version of `setState`. It's important to do that **any** time you're providing state information that's dependent on existing state.

There are other places you have to do the same sort of thing, including when you push to the array. Here are some further notes:

There's no reason to copy state here:

```
countSeconds = () => {
    let stateCopy = this.getStateCopy();
    let currentSeconds = stateCopy.secondsElapsed + 1;
    this.setState({secondsElapsed: currentSeconds});
}
```

...and (as I mentioned above) you must use the callback form to reliably modify state based on existing state. Instead:

```
countSeconds = () => {
    this.setState(({secondsElapsed}) => {secondsElapsed: secondsElapsed + 1});
};
```

Similarly in `captureTime`:

```
captureTime = (startOrStop) => {
    if (startOrStop) { // *** There's no reason for `=== true`
        this.setState(({timer, secondsElapsed}) => {timer: {...timer, screenshotStart: secondsElapsed}});
    } else { // *** Unless `startOrStop` may be missing or something, no need for `if` or `=== false`.
        this.setState(({timer, secondsElapsed}) => {
            const timingArray = [...timer.timingArray, secondsElapsed - timer.screenshotStart];
            const update = {
                timer: {
                    ...timer,
                    screenshotEnd: secondsElapsed,
                    timingArray,
                    averageTimePerUnit: timingArray.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
                }
            };
        });
    }
};
```

---

Side note: Your `copyState` function does a **shallow** state copy. So if you modify any properties on the objects it contains, you'll be directly modifying state, which you mustn't do in React.

Answer (score 1):

setState hooks overwrite the state with a new object always... that is their correct behavior.

you need to use a function within setState. not just pass in an object.

```
setState((prevState,prevProps)=>{
//logic to make a new object that you will return ... copy properties from prevState as needed.
 //something like const newState = {...prevState} //iffy myself on exact syntax

return newState

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getStateCopy` is only shallow cloning the existing state - anything nested is not cloned. To illustrate:

```js
const getStateCopy = () => Object.assign({}, state);
const state = {
  foo: 'bar',
  arr: [1, 2]
};

const shallowCopy = getStateCopy();
shallowCopy.foo = 'newFoo';
shallowCopy.arr.push(3);
console.log(state);
```

Either deep clone the state first instead, or use spread to add in the new properties you want:

```
countSeconds = () => {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1
    });
}
captureTime = (startOrStop) => {
    if (startOrStop === true) {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, timer: { ...this.timer, screenshotStart: this.state.secondsElapsed } });
    } else if (startOrStop === false) {
        const newTimingValue = this.state.secondsElapsed - this.state.timer.screenshotStart;
        const newTimingArray = [...this.state.timer.timingArray, newTimingValue];
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            timer: {
                ...this.timer,
                screenshotEnd: this.state.secondsElapsed,
                timingArray: newTimingArray,
                averageTimePerUnit: newTimingArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / newTimingArray.length,
            },
        });
    }
}
```

If `captureTime` is always called with either `true` or `false`, you can make things look a bit cleaner with:

```
captureTime = (startOrStop) => {
    if (startOrStop) {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, timer: { ...this.timer, screenshotStart: this.state.secondsElapsed } });
        return;
    }
    const newTimingValue = this.state.secondsElapsed - this.state.timer.screenshotStart;
    const newTimingArray = [...this.state.timer.timingArray, newTimingValue];
    // etc
```